# Duplicar registro automatizado SQL server

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

tengo el siguiente problema:

En la BDD tengo registros de miles de productos con la fecha de factura y la cantidad que se vendió. Lo que necesito es agregar registros para todos los códigos de productos que tengo registrados, tomando todas las fechas desde la primera registrada hasta la ultima (sin importar el cod de producto ) y agregar todos los meses que no están registrados por cada producto y agregar una cantidad cero para dicho mes.

Por ejemplo, se puede visualizar el problema con la siguiente  tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito lograr

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se me ocurre alguna sentencia en sql para solucionar este problema de forma automática, sin datos en duro, agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda, gracias de antemano.

PD: La versión que estoy utilizando es sql server 2008

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No vas a encontrar una sentencia que genere registros magicamente. Tendrias que por ejemplo agregar otra tabla con las fechas y hacer un join, para que agregue los 0 que hacen falta.. o mucho mejor un SP que arregle este lio. Si esto es para solucionar un problema de vista, te sugiero que lo arregles en la vista.

Comment: No entiendo la lógica para que AAA del 26/04 vaya a la salida como 14/4? podrías aclarar esto. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto no es tan simple como lo parece, pero básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es o tener una tabla calendario con datos para cada mes, o crear esa tabla en el momento. Te recomiendo que crees una tabla que ya contenga los meses que necesitas.

En todo caso, una solución es la siguiente:

```
-- Creación de datos de ejemplo
CREATE TABLE #TuTabla(Cod varchar(3), Cantidad int, Fecha date);

INSERT INTO #TuTabla 
VALUES  ('AAA',2,'20180125'),
        ('AAA',3,'20180426'),
        ('BBB',4,'20180527')
;

-- Código para obtener el resultado deseado
WITH Meses AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,number,B.MinMes) Mes
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(varchar(6),Fecha,112) + '01') MinMes, MAX(CONVERT(varchar(6),Fecha,112) + '01') MaxMes
                FROM #TuTabla) B
    WHERE A.type = 'P'
    AND DATEADD(MONTH,number,B.MinMes) <= B.MaxMes
)
SELECT  C.Cod,
        ISNULL(T.Cantidad,0) Cantidad,
        ISNULL(T.Fecha,M.Mes) Fecha
FROM Meses M
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Cod
            FROM #TuTabla) C
LEFT JOIN #TuTabla T
    ON C.Cod = T.Cod
    AND CONVERT(varchar(6),M.Mes,112) = CONVERT(varchar(6),T.Fecha,112)
ORDER BY C.Cod
;
```

[**Acá hay un demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6f24/1) online para que revises el código.

Y el resultado es:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ Cod ║ Cantidad ║   Fecha    ║
╠═════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ AAA ║        2 ║ 2018-01-25 ║
║ AAA ║        0 ║ 2018-02-01 ║
║ AAA ║        0 ║ 2018-03-01 ║
║ AAA ║        3 ║ 2018-04-26 ║
║ AAA ║        0 ║ 2018-05-01 ║
║ BBB ║        4 ║ 2018-05-27 ║
║ BBB ║        0 ║ 2018-04-01 ║
║ BBB ║        0 ║ 2018-03-01 ║
║ BBB ║        0 ║ 2018-02-01 ║
║ BBB ║        0 ║ 2018-01-01 ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```